# destructure an object from a function

Tags: javascript

I need some help with return and destructure an object from a function.
I want to assign new paras to what ever return from the function.

```
function someRes() {
const val1 = 1
const val2 = 2
    return {val1, val2}
}

const {val1, val2} = someRes()
const {val3, val4} = someRes()//this returns as undefined

console.log(val1, val2)
console.log(val3, val4) //console.log undefined
```

I understand that destructure a params is not like assign them to new params but still, Im looking for an elegant way to do it.

thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aliases during destructuring. When you use destructuring syntax, the variables created assumes the same name as the corresponding object properties. You can change that using the `:` while destructuring :

```js
function someRes() {
  const val1 = 1
  const val2 = 2
  return {
    val1,
    val2
  }
}

const {
  val1,
  val2
} = someRes()
const {
  val1: val3,
  val2: val4
} = someRes() 

console.log(val1, val2)
console.log(val3, val4)
```

Answer (score 3):

`someRes` returns an object with two properties `val1` and `val2`. [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) requires that you access properties by name so `{val3, val4}` returns `undefined` because the object doesn't have those properties.

It looks like you might want to return a tuple instead of an object from your function. [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring) is by index so naming is not constrained by property name.

```js
function someRes() {
  const val1 = 1;
  const val2 = 2;

  return [val1, val2];
}

const [val1, val2] = someRes();
const [val3, val4] = someRes();

console.log(val1, val2);
console.log(val3, val4);
```

Otherwise you can alias the second destructuring assignment as mentioned in the other answer

```js
function someRes() {
  const val1 = 1;
  const val2 = 2;

  return {val1, val2};
}

const {val1, val2} = someRes();
const {val1: val3, val2: val4} = someRes();

console.log(val1, val2);
console.log(val3, val4);
```